# Spring boot validation not working for all beans

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a `spring-boot:1.2.3` application and I'm having 2 validation issues:

- it works in @Path endpoints but not @Service or @Component classes
- it doesn't throw or log anything if the validation fails, it just returns a 400 without any additional information

These are the validation libraries that already come with `spring-boot:1.2.3`:

```
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.1.3.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.ext:jersey-bean-validation:jar:2.14:compile
```

These are the logging libraries that come with `spring-boot-starter-log4j`:

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j:jar:1.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.10:compile
[INFO] |  \- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
```

This validation works but doesn't log or show any stacktrace:

```
@Component
@Path("/validation-example")
public class ValidationExampleResource {

    @GET
    @Path("/{positiveNumber}")
    public int validationExample(@Min(0) @PathParam("positiveNumber") int positiveNumber) {
        ...
    }
}
```

But the validation doesn't work here at all:

```
@Service
public class ValidationExampleServiceImpl implements ValidationExampleService {

    @Override
    public int validationExample(@Min(0) int positiveNumber) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately no. If you figure it out, please let us know. I'm guessing this would work if I used Spring MVC controllers instead of JAX-RS Resource classes, but I'd like this to work with both, of course.

Comment: Which is weird is that I can't get it to work with Path endpoints

Comment: What jersey version are you using?

Comment: `2.14` as set by `spring-boot-dependencies:1.2.3.RELEASE`

Comment: you have missed the @ Valid.Please try with @ valid before min.

Answer (score 1):

Try this config. In my project it worked! Spring boot: `1.5.9.RELEASE`

```
@Slf4j
@Service
@Validated
public class ValidationService {

    @Validated(CreateGroup.class)
    public void create(@Valid User user) {
        log.info("验证服务业务的作用");
    }

    public void basic(@NotNull(message = "名称不能为空") String name) {

    }

}
```

[Details](https://github.com/Percy0601/boot-features/tree/master/boot-features-validation)

Answer (score 0):

In order for the validation to work, you need to add @Valid

```
@Component
@Path("/validation-example")
public class ValidationExampleResource {

    @GET
    @Path("/{positiveNumber}")
    public int validationExample(@Valid @Min(0) @PathParam("positiveNumber") int positiveNumber) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: @cahen here is an example https://fbflex.wordpress.com/2014/06/02/spring-boot-recipe-reading-and-validating-lists-of-configuration-properties/